# Insert data into one row only in loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables (table_server) & (table_comment).
When i put data into table_comment inside of table_server loop, it puts data inside every row in the table.

**Is there a way to just insert data in only one row based by row-parent_id?
So if i write comment in row 4 then it only logs in row 4.**

[Example of my table_comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMQih.jpg)

```
echo "<ul>";
if($result-> num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){

        $theRowId = $row['ID'];

        if(isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])){
            $comment = $_POST['comments'];

            if(!empty($comment)){
                $sqlss = "INSERT INTO table_comment(parent_id, comment) VALUES ('$theRowId', '$comment')";
                $resultss = $conn->query($sqlss);
            }
        }
```

My form html

```
<form method='POST' action='index.php' id='singleAmountForm'>
   <textarea class='txtarea' id='".$row['ID']."' name='comments' placeholder='Comment...' rows=6></textarea>
   <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit' id='insertComment' class='visa-fler'>Add comment</button>
</form>
```

[View example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmPHw.jpg)
table_info = table_server

Comment: This is hard to understand. What is the first query whose results you're looping over? Why are you using a loop if you don't want to use all the rows? Or maybe the first query needs a `WHERE` clause so it only fetches the one row that you want to use.

Comment: Are you sure you even need the PHP loop? Why not use `INSERT INTO table_comment(parent_id, comment) SELECT ID, '$comment' FROM table_server WHERE ...`

Comment: Your form needs to send an input field that says which row you're commenting on. Then you use that in the `WHERE` clause of the `SELECT` so you only get that row ID.

Comment: Thank you fort your answer @Barmar , My first loop for selecting all server items/rows and inside those rows i have comments(looping throw all comments). what I need is to be able to comment on each table_server row, so each row has its own comment field

Comment: How does the user tell it which row they're commenting on?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's my problem and I apologize if if the question is stupid

Comment: Can you show what the form HTML looks like?

Comment: Put it in the question so you can format it properly.

Comment: @Barmar i edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the row ID in a hidden input or the value of the submit button.

```
<form method='POST' action='index.php' id='singleAmountForm".$row['ID']."'>
   <textarea class='txtarea' id='".$row['ID']."' name='comments' placeholder='Comment...' rows=6></textarea>
   <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit' id='insertComment".$row['ID']."' class='visa-fler' value='".$row['ID']"'>Add comment</button>
</form>
```

I've also changed all the IDs in the form so they include the row ID, because you shouldn't have duplicate IDs in the DOM (but maybe these elements don't even need IDs, since they change dynamically).

Then you can insert the comment (this doesn't need to be done in the loop). It's best to use a prepared statement to protect against SQL injection.

```
if(!empty($_POST['commentSubmit']) && !empty($_POST['comments'])){
    $sqlss = "INSERT INTO table_comment(parent_id, comment) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlss);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['commentSubmit'], $_POST['comments']);
    $stmt->execute($sqlss) or die($stmt->error);
}
```